# Have user sign up with Google and get redirected back to the site afterwards?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using GAE with python and I can ask users to sign in with Google using:

`loginURL = (users.create_login_url(self.request.path))`

This gives me a link that lets users *sign in* and get redirected to my site.
However some users do not have a Google ID,
Is there any way to let them **sign up** for one and be redirected to my site?

I know there is no:

`signupURL = (users.create_signup_url(self.request.path))`

That is the kind of thing I am looking for, asking the user to sign up and have her quickly redirected when she is done.

Thank you very much for any insight.

Comment: I have no answer, but better don't restrict this system to Google. OpenIDs can be provided by many other providers...

Comment: Just for reference: what happens when a user is sent to the login URL? Don't they see a login screen containing a link "sign up for a Google account"? And if so, does that process eventually redirect to the place that the login would have redirected to? It might be that Google is expecting you just to use the result of `create_login_url`, and let the user decide whether they need to sign up or use an existing account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is possible to direct a user to the subscription page.
It is just a little tricky:

The link you get to sign in looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://study-wise.appspot.com/login&ltmpl=gm&shdf=ChULEgZhaG5hbWUaCVN0dWR5V2lzZQwSAmFoIhRSjkTO01_PtfPG9VN12NFsbyludCgBMhQrFIvLEm2lqCc65PvVrBca1skQRA
```

Where in my case: http://study-wise.appspot.com/login is the url of the application.
The shdf appears to be some key google uses to track the request. But I have not found any clues about it

Now the sign up link will be:

```
https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fappengine.google.com%2F_ah%2Fconflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fstudy-wise.appspot.com%2Flogin&shdf=ChULEgZhaG5hbWUaCVN0dWR5V2lzZQwSAmFoIhRSjkTO01_PtfPG9VN12NFsbyludCgBMhQrFIvLEm2lqCc65PvVrBca1skQRA&service=ah&ltmpl=gm
```

The url:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin
```

Was replaced by

```
https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount
```

and

```
passive=true
```

Has been removed. As far as I see no other changes have been made.

Here is the python function I wrote:

```
def login2Subscribe(link):
    return link.replace('https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin', 'https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount').replace('passive=true', '')
```

You can use it like this:

```
viewVals['subscribe'] = login2Subscribe(users.create_login_url("/login"))
```

Answer (score 1):

When your user goes to the login url, there is a red SIGN UP button on the top.  They can go sign up there.

It took me a second to find too, unfortunately you can't change the login page.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I want them to go directly to the sign up link?